# Using a CONCAT with GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, group-concat

I have to export some data to a excel file. This data is from a table named "tb_Forms" and has a multiple relation in another table named "tb_Movement", as shown below

```
+----------+---------------------+
| tb_Forms |                     |
+----------+---------------------+
| FormsId  | Description         |
| 1        | "form 1"            |
| 2        | "form 2"            |
| 3        | "form 3"            |
+----------+---------------------+
```

```
+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------+
|   tb_Movement   |               |                   |              |        |                       |
+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------+
| MovementId      | FirstAnswer   | SecondAnswer      | ResponseDate | UserFk | FormsFk               |
| 1               | "Lorem Ipsum" | "dolor sit amet"  | 2018-07-31   | 1      | 1                     |
| 2               | "consectetur" | "adipiscing elit" | 2018-08-01   | 2      | 1                     |
+-----------------+---------------+-------------------+--------------+--------+-----------------------+
```

```
+----------+---------------------+
| tb_Users |                     |
+----------+---------------------+
| UserId   | Name                |
| 1        | João Silva          |
| 2        | Maria Oliveira      |
+----------+---------------------+
```

I want to find a way to get two results like:

```
Result
First Remark: "Lorem Ipsum",
Second Remark: "dolor sit amet" in 2018-07-31 by João Silva
First Remark: "consectetur", 
Second Remark: "adipiscing elit" in 2018-08-01 by Maria Oliveira
```

But I can only get the first result (by João Silva) and nothing more.
Here is the query I did:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(
    "First Remark: ", mv.FirstRemark,
    "\rSecond Remark: ", mv.SecondRemark,
    "\rin ", mv.ResponseDate, " by ",
    (SELECT Name FROM tb_Users WHERE UserId = mv.UserFk)
) SEPARATOR ',')
FROM tb_Movement mv 
WHERE mv.FormsFk = 1;
```

I already try:

```
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
```

..because the remarks field could be very large, but this not appear to be the solution.

I have to concat all answers like this because each Form row also has to be a unique row in excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('First Remark: ', mv.FirstRemark,
                    '\rSecond Remark: ', mv.SecondRemark,
                    '\rin ', mv.ResponseDate, 
                    ' by ', u.name
                    SEPARATOR ','
                   )
FROM tb_Movement mv LEFT JOIN
     tb_Users u
     ON u.userId = mv.UserFK
WHERE mv.FormsFk = 1;
```

Notes:

- The standard string delimiter in SQL is the single quote.
- `GROUP_CONCAT()` handles multiple arguments, so `CONCAT()` is not necessary.
- You need to use a `JOIN`.  Using a correlated subquery in an aggregation query either produces unexpected results or an error -- neither is desirable.
- A `LEFT JOIN` is closer to your intention, so `NULL` foreign key references are not filtered out.